# Ошибка TypeError: humans() takes no arguments

Tags: python

Учу python по книжке "Укус питона". Там был код, похожий на мой (почти такой-же). Проблема в том, что когда я запускаю свой код, то он выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Python/objvar.py", line 24, in <module>
    igor = humans("Игорь")
TypeError: humans() takes no arguments
```

Заранее благодарен, если скажите, где я ошибся/что неправильно написал. Вот код:

```
class humans:

    humans_count = 0

    def _init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("В комнате есть {0}" .format(self.name))

        humans.humans_count += 1
    def __del__(self): #Выполняется при удалении (del)
        print("{0} вышел из комнаты" .format(self.name))

        human.humans_count -= 1

        if humans_count == 1:
            print("Остался один человек")
        elif humans == 0:
            print("В комнате не осталось людей")
    def count(self):
        print("В комнате {0} человек" .format(Humans.humans_count))

    count = staticmethod(count)

igor = humans("Игорь")
igor.count()
alex = humans("Алекс")
alex.count()

del alex
del igor

humans.count()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка `TypeError: humans() takes no arguments` вызвана неправильным объявлением конструктора класса.

Функция-конструктор **обязательно** должна называться `__init__`, и никак иначе. У вас же она называется `_init__`.

Кроме того, в программе есть логические ошибки и ошибки с несуществующими переменными:

- переменная `Humans` в методе `count` не существует;
- метод `count` статическим быть не должен;
- обращение к данным объекта реализуется не через название класса (`human.humans_count`), а через параметр метода self (`self.humans_count`)

Answer (score 1):

Не согласен с предыдущим оратором местами. Count вполне можно и нужно делать статическим методом. У вас просто напутано много - human вместо humans, например, и есть обращение к переменным вообще без указания объекта/класса. Я всё исправил:

```
class humans:

    humans_count = 0

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        print("В комнате есть {0}" .format(self.name))
        humans.humans_count += 1

    def __del__(self): #Выполняется при удалении (del)
        print("{0} вышел из комнаты" .format(self.name))
        humans.humans_count -= 1
        if humans.humans_count == 1:
            print("Остался один человек")
        elif humans.humans_count == 0:
            print("В комнате не осталось людей")

    def count():
        print("В комнате {0} человек" .format(humans.humans_count))


igor = humans("Игорь")
humans.count()
alex = humans("Алекс")
humans.count()

del alex
del igor

humans.count()
```

Вывод программы:

```
В комнате есть Игорь
В комнате 1 человек
В комнате есть Алекс
В комнате 2 человек
Алекс вышел из комнаты
Остался один человек
Игорь вышел из комнаты
В комнате не осталось людей
В комнате 0 человек
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Название класса пишется с большой буквы и не как иначе.
2. Сейчас вы пишите название класса с humans, а потом исправляете на Hemans согласное Pep8, и вызов humans.humans_count += 1 уже не работает, это плохая практика нужно писать slef.humans_count += 1. Как правильно заметил человек выше.
3. И в данном случае я не вижу смысла использовать статический метод так как статический метод работает только с переданными в него отдельно аргументами, а если по выпендриваться можно использовать класс метод.

Comment: пожалуйста, исправьте опечатки, нажав [edit]